# How to increase memory and cache size for application pool in IIS 7 efficiently

Tags: performance, caching, iis, iis-7

I have searched the internet for how to increase memory and cache size for application pools in IIS 7 but all topics are diffused and I don't know the effect of combining those settings together.

Can somebody describe how I can increase memory and cache size for application pools in IIS 7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my understanding output cache can be set only at the IIS level and not specifically for an application pool. Whatever is set at the IIS level is applied to all the web sites under it. So effectively you can apply a max cache size at the web application level.

If you are using windows 7 professional (IIS features vary depending on the operating system) if you open IIS manager and click on the server name, in the features view there is an Output Caching feature. You can edit that to set the max cache size. If you set it to a very high value, it will use up a lot of your RAM and could deteriorate the performance of the whole box.

[image]

[image]

THe application pool itself can have a private memory limit and a virtual memory limit.

Primary memory limit: Maximum amount of private memory (in KB) a worker process can consume before causing the application pool to recycle.

Virtual memory Limit: Maximum amount of virtual memory (in KB) a worker process can consume before causing the application pool to recycle.

Both the above settings are set to 0 by default, which means there is no limit set.

**Long story short: Raising the output cache size at the IIS server level is the best option that suits your needs.**

Comment: For my web page the size field is deactivated, so I cannot change it. Is there a way to activate it?