# how to solve system.outofmemoryexception in c#

Tags: c#

When we upload a video and click into button to convert video into thumbnail image using this code it generate an error 
'System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.'

We are using this code

```
fpUplaodVideo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/SiteUserID_" + SiteUserID + "/UploadVideo/" + fpUplaodVideo.FileName));
```

error will occur on this line

```
System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/SiteUserID_" + SiteUserID + "/UploadVideo/") + fpUplaodVideo.FileName);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162524/how-to-increase-memory-and-cache-size-for-application-pool-in-iis-7-efficiently check this.

Comment: Please give suggestion ASAP

Comment: Your conversion to a thumbnail image is a bit simplistic, you cannot load a video by simply opening as if it was an image, you will have to do a bit more effort there. Also, asking for an "ASAP" suggestion seems a bit pushy, AKN has the correct answer which explains why you get the error, for converting the video to a thumbnail, I think you will need to do a bit more work

Comment: please try to see [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

System.Drawing.Image.FromFile will return *OutOfMemoryException* for below reason

1. The file does not have a valid image format.
2. GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) for Image.FromFile says this:

> **OutOfMemoryException**
>
> The file does not have a valid image format.
>
> -or-
>
> GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Granted, this is a bad and nonsensical use of the `OutOfMemoryException`, but at least it's documented.

As to why this is thrown, it's quite simple - you're trying to load a *video* file as an *image* file. The same docs show that the following formats are supported:

> - BMP
> - GIF
> - JPEG
> - PNG
> - TIFF

I assume your "UploadVideo" is none of these. In fact, I'm not sure why you assumed that this would produce a thumbnail image. Try looking for a specific library for that. This might be a good start:
[Thumbnail video C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674227/thumbnail-video-c-sharp)