# How to increase Output Cache memory Size in IIS 8.5?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, web-applications, crystal-reports

I am getting `System.OutOfMemoryException` when I run crystal report on web application because of huge file.

To solve this issue I am trying to increase the size of Caching memory on IIS.

I saw on this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162524/how-to-increase-memory-and-cache-size-for-application-pool-in-iis-7-efficiently) to increase the size. But for me it is disable to change the size like below pic

[image: picture].

Comment: Did you try to configure output cache throw Web.config file?

Comment: @ArturLavrov how to do it?.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the caching setting at the server level in the ApplicationHost.config file or at the site, application, or at the directory level in a Web.config file, using `<caching>` section.

For example, the following code example sets the maximum output cache size to 1 gigabyte and sets the maximum size of a response that can be stored in the output cache to 512 kilobytes.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxCacheSize="1000" maxResponseSize="512000"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**NB**

The  element is included in the default installation of IIS 7 and higher.

I hope that my answer could help you to achieve your aim. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/caching/) contains a lot of nitty-gritty details and more detailed explanation.